# Animating View every time the View Controller appears?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation, viewwillappear

I have a `UIViewController` that's triggered every time a `UITabBarButtonItem` is clicked. The problem is that it's sort of a menu, that consists of a `UIView` that slides from the bottom of the screen up.

Now, initially, the bottom constraint is set to -500 so it's off the screen. I've created a function that sets the constraints back to 100 with some animation. The problem is that I thought that if I call the function in the `viewWillAppear()` it will be animated every time. But it's not. I also tried to reset the constraint back to -500 in the `viewDidDisappear()` so it's off screen before the next time it's triggered.

Doesn't work. It works just the first time. I miss something or I'm calling it at the wrong place...

```
    class PostVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        animateMenu()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        menuBottomConstraint.constant = -500
    }

    func animateMenu() {
        menuBottomConstraint.constant = 100
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 1.0,
            delay: 0.0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut,
            animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            },
            completion: nil
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but you should not hardcode `true` when calling `super.viewWill[Disa|A]ppear`. Pass the `animated` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time when you change `constant` value of your `Constraint` and you will see effect then you must call `layoutIfNeeded()` method.

in your code:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    menuBottomConstraint.constant = -500
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

I also proposes to replace the `viewWillAppear` functions with `viewDidAppear`